# Бесплатный ли сервис reCaptcha?

Tags: веб-программирование

Бесплатный ли сервис reCaptcha ? https://www.google.com/recaptcha
Или за него нужно платить? И если нужно платить, то плата взимается за просмотр reCaptcha или только в том случаи если пользователь набрал правильную reCaptcha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно же бесплатный. С помощью этого сервиса оцифровывались книги и  распознавались фрагменты снимков из Google Street View; как правило, это фрагменты, на которых изображены номера зданий. Сейчас же какого-либо общественно полезной функции Recaptcha не нёсет. Теперь пользователю предлагают просто поставить галочку в чекбоксе, после нажатия на чекбокс пользователю могут предложить выбрать все картинки, например, выбрать все торты.

Comment: [пишут](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html): "reCAPTCHA is a free service ..."