# Можно ли компании использовать reCaptcha v2 бесплатно?

Tags: recaptcha

Покопавшись в документации reCaptcha столкнулся с прайсом для использования:
[image: Цена за использование reCaptcha]

Потом наткнулся на [Обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473931/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81-recaptcha), в котором говорится, что использование reCaptcha бесплатно. Исходя из этих противоречий у меня возник вопрос, может ли компания использовать бесплатно reCaptcha v2, если количество вызовов проверки более 1 млн?

Answer (score 1):

Нет! Рекаптча - Google сервис, для его использования (в лицензии) нужен Google Cloud Account, с оплачены Google Services вроде как 15 евро в год.

Один лям, это для приватного использования. Если сможешь удостоверить суд что лям ты используешь только в личных целях, то юзай свободно.

Я своим клиентам изначально ставлю ставку 50 евреев в год, на использование Google сервисов. Из которых мне остаётся 1-10 евро. Там зависит от кушанья. Иногда бывает и в минус, но это уже мои проблемы